# jQuery dialog won't open on one page but works on others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a web page for downloading data. A jQuery dialog is supposed to open when the 'download full dataset' button is clicked.  It works on some pages and not on others and I can't figure out why!

This is a [working page](https://www.uvm.edu/femc/data/archive/project/ambient-air-monitoring-for-ozone/dataset/ny-ozone/data) (click Download Options -> Download Full Dataset, and the dialog opens).

This is a [non-working page](https://www.uvm.edu/femc/data/archive/project/indicators_dashboard/dataset/tblindicators/data).

It's the same code, so I can't figure out why it isn't working on the second page!  I don't see anything in the console or network tab causing an issue. Any help is appreciated!

html:

```
<div id="explorer-download-options" style="display:none;">
  <small><button type="button" id='explorer-download-all' 
    class="btn btn-primary data-download-button downloadButton data-archive-button">
      Download Full Dataset</button></small>
  <small><button type="button" id='explorer-download-preview' 
    class="btn btn-primary data-download-button downloadButton data-archive-button">
      Download Data Subset</button></small>
      
  <div id="explorer-current-filter">
    <h4>Current Filters</h4><small>Here's were some plain-english filter text would go</small></div>
    
  <div class="cf"></div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('.downloadButton').click(function() {
  ($(this).hasClass('downloadVersionButton')) 
    ? $('#downloadForm').attr('downloadVersion', true)
    : $('#downloadForm').attr('downloadVersion', false);
  
  $('#downloadForm').dialog("open");
  
  if ($(this).attr('id') == 'explorer-download-preview') {
    $('#filtered').val(1) //Set flag indicating filtered query
  } else {
    $('#filtered').val(0) //Set flag indicating not a filtered query
  }
});
```

We are on very old versions of jquery and jquery-ui but are in the middle of upgrading on our development servers.  However, both pages are using the same versions and one works, so I don't think that's the problem...

Let me know if you have any other questions that would help troubleshoot.  Thanks!

Comment: @isherwood that's fixed now (I hadn't published it externally yet).  Nothing shows in the console.

Comment: @isherwood sorry about that!  Should be fixed now

Comment: There is no Download Options button or link on that page.

Comment: *"This is non-working page"* => no datatable, no buttons, "*this data cannot be previewed*".  Please ensure all relevant code is in the question not on external pages and certainly not on pages in development that will change.

Comment: sorry, I guess I can't give access to that data.  This can be closed